# Advantages of Nengo for memory related tasks

Tags: cognitive-modeling, computational-modeling, nef, spa

What are some of the advantages [Nengo](http://www.nengo.ca/) offer as a framework for modeling memory
related cognitive processes?

Comment: Hi @KeremDonmez, could you please provide a little more context to the question? What is Nango exactly, and why do you ask? Is there some research you're doing? You may edit this into the question.

Comment: Hey Kerem, I'm one of the developers of Nengo. For me to be able to answer you question, I would really appreciate it if you could help me understand what types of advantages you're looking for and what you're comparing to.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're looking for a more general discussion, please consider posting in [the Nengo forums](https://forum.nengo.ai/).